# Has the anime for To Love-Ru caught up with the manga?

Tags: to-love-ru

I see there are 7 anime series including OVAs and I was wondering if the anime and manga are aligned perfectly.

What I mean is, did the anime end before the manga and do I have to continue with the manga after the series? If I have to continue, which chapter do I start at? And has the manga finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has the manga finished? Did the anime end before the manga?

The manga has finished, but there's no news about the continuation of the anime adaptation for *Darkness* as of current writing:

- *To Love-Ru*

  - Manga: 2006 - 2009
  - Anime: 2008 - 2010 (original & *Motto*)
- *To Love-Ru Darkness*

  - Manga: Nov 2010 - Apr 2017
  - Anime: Oct 2012 - Oct 2015 (original & *2nd*)

> Do I have to continue with the manga after the series? Which chapter do I start at?

Since the anime had ended before the manga finished, you have to pick up the rest on the manga. Here is the detail for all animated series:

- *To Love-Ru*: Most of the content is an anime original story that does not conform with the manga.
- *To Love-Ru OVA*: Included in the limited edition of manga volume 13-18, the story conforms with the manga.

  1. Chapter 100-102
  2. Chapter 73, 104
  3. ?
  4. Chapter 93-98
  5. Chapter 141
  6. Chapter 142, 139, 143
- *Motto To Love-Ru*: A reboot of the original anime, the story is now based on the manga more faithfully. Each episode consists of 3 sub-episodes.

  1. Chapter 49 | Chapter 87, 88 | Chapter 74, 107
  2. Chapter 146 | Chapter 54 | Chapter 75, 76
  3. Chapter 120 | Chapter 109 | Chapter 106
  4. Chapter 61 | Chapter 105 | Chapter 108
  5. Chapter 81 | Chapter 85 | Chapter 136, 137
  6. Chapter 113, 114 | Chapter 70 | Chapter 80
  7. Chapter 45 | Chapter 123 | Chapter 64, 65
  8. Chapter 115, 156 | Chapter 43, 44, *bangai-hen* | Chapter 139
  9. Chapter 130 | Chapter 152, 153 | Chapter 154
  10. Chapter 129 | Chapter 147 | Chapter 155
  11. Chapter 157 | Chapter 158 | Chapter 116-118
  12. Chapter 119, 122, 159 | Chapter 160-161 | Chapter 162
- *To Love-Ru Darkness*: Follows the manga faithfully, covers up to chapter 19 + *bangai-hen*.

  1. Chapter 1
  2. Chapter 2, 3
  3. Chapter 3, 4
  4. Chapter 1, 5, 6
  5. Chapter 7, 8
  6. Chapter 8, 9
  7. Chapter 10, 11
  8. Chapter 12, *bangai-hen*
  9. Chapter 11, 13
  10. Chapter 14, 15
  11. Chapter 11, 15, 16
  12. Chapter *bangai-hen*, 17
  13. OVA 1 (Episode 0): Chapter 0 | *bangai-hen* | *bangai-hen*
  14. OVA 2: Chapter 19 | *bangai-hen* | *bangai-hen*
  15. OVA 3: Chapter 18 | *bangai-hen*
  16. OVA 4: Chapter *bangai-hen* | 28 | *bangai-hen*
  17. OVA 5: Chapter *bangai-hen*
  18. OVA 6: Chapter *bangai-hen*
- *To Love-Ru Darkness 2nd*: Covers up to chapter 55

  1. Chapter 26
  2. Chapter 20, 27
  3. Chapter 21, 22
  4. Chapter 23, 24
  5. Chapter 25, *bangai-hen*
  6. Chapter 29, *bangai-hen*
  7. Chapter 30
  8. Chapter 31-33
  9. Chapter 33-35
  10. Chapter 36, 37
  11. Chapter 38-40
  12. Chapter 40-43
  13. Chapter 43-45
  14. Chapter 45-47
  15. OVA 7: Chapter *bangai-hen* | 38
  16. OVA 8: Chapter 48, 49 | 50
  17. OVA 9: Chapter 54 | 55

---

Source: [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_LOVE%E3%82%8B_-%E3%81%A8%E3%82%89%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8B-#.E3.82.A2.E3.83.8B.E3.83.A1)